# How to get rid of border in wordpress calendar plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, border

www.yadinsoffer.com/personaltrainer/#schedule

How can I get rid of the border lines on top and bottom of the calendar booking section? I'm sure its relatively simple but I just can't seem to find out how.

Also, if anyone knows by any chance how to make the text boxes a bit round rather than boxes that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use CSS. Do some research and if you can't figure it out update the question with what you've tried.

Comment: Tried erasing all the "border" elements in the Plugin CSS, still no change. Tried adding what you said to plugin css and to index css, still nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css file:

```
.rcalendar .ui-datepicker table {
    border: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: Tried erasing all the "border" elements in the Plugin CSS, still no change. Tried adding what you said to plugin css and to index css, still nothing. Thanks

Comment: Adding the css that I supplied should absolutely remove the border. I tested it in the example page you supplied and it worked. Have you made any other changes since?